# How to transform combineLatest to switchMap?

Tags: rxjs

I have to observables, i know there is a way to transform combineLatest to switchMap but i dont get it

```
combineLatest([
      faviconServiceOutgoingEvents.ready.listen().pipe(mapTo(true), startWith(false)),
      this.brandService.brandName$,
    ]).subscribe(([isServiceReady, brandName]) => {
      if (isServiceReady) {
        faviconServiceIncomingEvents.changeIcon.send(brandName);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

solution was near

```
faviconServiceOutgoingEvents.ready
  .listen()
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() => {
      return this.brandService.brandName$;
    }),
  )
  .subscribe(brandName => faviconServiceIncomingEvents.changeIcon.send(brandName));
```